# MEAN stack app: I can't show my image

Tags: angular, image, typescript

So I'm working on a MEAN stack movie app. So I uploaded an image and saved a reference (e.g '1521991102156.png') in my database.

Now, when I load the page I want to show this image, but I just don't know what to add to my img image. Everything I've tried so far just doesn't seem to work. Does someone know how to do this?

**This is my template: when the profile picture is not uploaded it lets the user do that first, otherwise it just shows the profile picture. The picture however doesn't show here.**

```
<div class="profilePicSection">
        <div *ngIf="!user?.profilePicture.uploaded; else profilePic" class="form-group">
            <label for="file">Choose File</label>
            <input type="file"
                   id="file"
                   (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)">
        </div>
        <ng-template #profilePic>
            <img [src]="profilePicLink" alt="heyho">
        </ng-template>
    </div>
```

**This is the component: when I open the page I try to get the name of the profile picture file in the database and enter it into the link. I succeed in this, but it doesn't show the picture so I assume there is something wrong with my path.**

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.authService.getUserStatistics(localStorage.getItem('userId'))
            .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
            .subscribe(result => {
                console.log(result.user);
                this.statistics = result.statistics;
                this.user = result.user;
                this.profilePicLink = '/assets/app/uploads/' + result.user.profilePicture.name
            });
    }
```

**This is the structure of the app that I'm using:**

[image]

Comment: No it's not because I changed the file and then followed the instruction in the other post but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! They seemed really close to me. I will remove the close vote.